# The result of $n$ iterations of $x_{\text{output}}=\arctan\left(c\tan(x_{\text{input}})\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The function is given by:

$$x_{\text{output}}=\arctan\left(c\tan(x_{\text{input}})\right)$$

where $c$ is a constant between $0$ and $1$.

After an output is found, the output becomes the input for the next iteration.

I would like to know how to find the angle (or $x_{\text{output}}$) after $n$ iterations.

I could make a table, but if $n$ is large this is tedious...

Thanks!

Comment: How could I solve this then? Do I have to put it into a program?

Comment: If you know any programming, it's very easy to make an iterating loop for this. By the way, do you know the initial value for $x$? The very first value?

Comment: What do you mean "solve"? What are you going to use this recurrence for?

Comment: Well, its a model of a bouncing ball where c is the coefficient of restiution, and x is the change in angle after the bounce

Comment: So i'm trying to find the angle after the nth bounce, where x_output is the angle after the bounce

Comment: Seems like a complicated model for a bouncing ball. Maybe a simpler model would be $x_{\text{new}} = c x_{\text{old}}$ for $0<c<1$

Comment: Instead of the angle, I would recommend looking at the bounce height. A model for the height is easy to derive, and you can then just take the arctan of that result.

Comment: let's say "c" is 0.7, is there a function that will yield the output angle for nth iteration?

Comment: Yes the input angle is known as 53.4935

Comment: You could also model this using the horizontal and vertical velocities immediately before and after each bounce. You seem to assume the vertical velocity decreases by a factor $c$ each time while the horizontal velocity remains constant. This would imply the ball does not gain or lose any rotational speed during any bounce. I’m not sure how realistic this is, but it’s simple, and it gives you Percy’s answer with a minimal amount of trigonometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\arctan(c\tan x)$$
$$f^2(x)=\arctan(c\tan\arctan(c\tan x))=\arctan(c^2\tan x)$$
since $\tan\arctan x=x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ (the other way round is not $x$).

Repeating, we get
$$f^n(x)=\arctan(c^n\tan x)$$
So iterations of the function can be computed by "powering up" $c$ and then applying the tangent/arctangent formula in one shot.

Comment: Thanks so much!